# greenDao importing classes in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, greendao

I'm trying to include in my project GreenDAO ORM, useless to say that there is no good tutorial that makes it work from scratch and there is ridiculous documentation on the official site. I used this [greendao tutorial](http://www.devteam83.com/en/blog/detail/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1) and made all intermediary steps to generating classes with gradle task. But now I'm stuck, Android Studio gives me an error for every generated class like:

**Cannot resolve symbol *'AbstractDaoMaster'***. All imports are actually in place but there is no way to make it work.

Things I tried:
invalidating caches 
updating AS to 1.2.1.1

I have iMac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

I have no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had to update build.gradle in the app module with:

```
compile files('libs/greendao.jar')
```

and manually sync gradle scripts with project files. After that, all dependencies are met.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation on the official site it's a bit old, for Eclipse projects. Using Android Studio I always follow [this tutorial](http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/), it worked always like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry I didn't find your question in time - the answer was already in the [2nd part](http://www.devteam83.com/en/blog/detail/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-2#part_02) of the tutorial you mentioned:

```
compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.7.jar')
```

Answer (score 1):

For the future, I really recommend adding Gradle dependency for greenDAO, instead of a jar file. It's more flexible and easy this way. Just add `compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:2.1.0'` to *build.gradle* and sync it. You can always check the last version [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.greenrobot%22%20AND%20a%3A%22greendao-generator%22).

See this [blog post](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/tutorial-how-to-integrate-greendao/) for a step by step tutorial with explanation.